# EHOSTUNREACH on UDP recvmsg

Tags: linux, sockets

Little bit confused on this issue :-).  I have some code running on Ubuntu 10.04, which is using the recvmsg call to receive Audio UDP packets.  This piece is part of a bigger SIP client which I've been testing with a remote system across the net.

Typically I am able to establish a call no problem and audio happily travels from the remote source to my program.  However after a random amount of time I'm running into a read error on the port.  When this happens I get the errno EHOSTUNREACH.  On this error I shutdown my port and kill the connection.

The strange thing about this is that I was under the impression that this would happen in response to an ICMP message.  Perhaps due to a momentary network glitch.  However after reproducing this issue and doing a full packet capture, all I saw where ICMP pings and responses.  I didn't see any of the ICMP error messages that the kernel interprets as EHOSTUNREACH.

My UDP port is pretty basic.  I can post the code if its really needed.  But this is just a basic SOCK_DGRAM. The socket is able to receive data for upwards of 8 hours sometimes before it hits this error condition.

Any ideas how I can further tackle this issue.  I'm trying to understand why I'm receiving this errno with no ICMP message to correlate it with.

Comment: Just to add on to this a little.  My UDP socket is indeed RTP.  And I have an RTCP socket paired with it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same socket to send packets out with?  Or a different socket sharing the same port? I'm curious if it's possible another socket is actually generating the error.

I remember years ago dealing with ICMP messages causing both sendto and recvfrom to fail 
intermittently like you describe. And if I recall, the workaround is to just ignore it and do another recvfrom/recvmsg.

As to why you are getting that error code in the absence of seeing an ICMP message on the wire is beyond me. Are you certain you are dismissing the ICMP messages you observed as "pings and responses" correctly? ICMP messages don't have port numbers, so it's possible that all sockets (or a random one) associated with that remote host return this error code.

I thought there might be an ioctl to disable this behavior, but I couldn't find it.

A similar discussion [here](http://www.textndata.com/forums/ignore-icmp-port-unreachable-wsaeconnreset-37433.html).

Comment: Hi Selbie.  I use this socket for sending and receiving.  But the error only occurs on the receive, not the send typically.  So I tried to keep thing simple with my packet capture.  I essentially just captured all traffic going between IP A and B.  After I reproduced I filtered by ICMP.  And then when I saw the pings and replies, I just filtered out those ICMP types and nothing was remaining.  Looking at that article, it sounds like this is a transient error and maybe I just need to ignore that error and keep the socket open on that port?

Comment: I added some code to ignore the error a certain number of times.  This fixed the issue.  Thanks for the information Selbie.